# Where can I find an organic photoconductive film (OPF), Camera or Sensor alone?

Tags: sensor, fujifilm, panasonic, cmos-image-sensor, rolling-shutter

This technology was [announced in 2016](https://news.panasonic.com/global/press/data/2016/02/en160203-6/en160203-6.html), but I couldn't find any trace or update about it later. Is there any camera using it ? If not how can I buy any from Panasonic/Fujifilm ?

Comment: @Rob [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelClark - Done. To me it seemed less than an answer, more effort might indeed find a bare sensor somewhere, so I only posted the update to the article linked in the question as a comment.

Comment: It is helpful information, which is the standard for being an "answer"here at SE. It doesn't need to completely answer the question to be considered a valid and helpful contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest update to that announcement is from two months ago: "[Panasonic unveils 'industry-first' 8K organic image sensor with global shutter](https://m.dpreview.com/news/1440456457/panasonic-unveils-industry-first-8k-organic-image-sensor-with-global-shutter)", as the article mentions they have a prototype and Apple has bought a competing technology - since this idea has been floating around for a half dozen years I'd expect it will be a few more until it's available/affordable.